# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController::show(), -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I use infyom generator to generat laravel template and basically i got the create, adit and show page. I now want to create additional show pages to display  same record in my show page using a different layout.
1. I created a poo.blade.php

2. I created a route

```php
Route::get('/poo', 'VehicleController@show');
```

I did not create a new controller as i want to use same controller and same show method since i am only doing layout modification.
When i open the http://localhost:8000/poo page i get this error:

```
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController::show(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

and when i try http://localhost:8000/vehicles/poo i GET 404 ERROR

I want to create an anchor tag to open his new page. 
What is the best wat to get this done
The show method of my VehiclController has the following codes:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $vehicle = $this->vehicleRepository->find($id);

        if (empty($vehicle)) {
            Flash::error('Vehicle not found');

            return redirect(route('vehicles.index'));
        }
        $invoices  = $vehicle->invoices;

        return view('vehicles.show')
        ->with('vehicle', $vehicle)
        ->with('invoices', $invoices);;
    }

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `show()` function takes an `$id` so you need to pass an `$id` with the *URL* you're sending.

So adjust the route to accept an id:

```
Route::get('/poo/{id}', 'VehicleController@show');
```

Then call the URL like this:

```
  //show record with an id of 1
  http://localhost:8000/poo/1
```

Comment: Thanks your answer really gave me a heads up. The show function was still returning the vehicle show so i created a new function 'poo' to return poo after processing and its much closer to what i want, Thanks once again.